# RIngBuffer with Spin

Tags: c++, multithreading

I just went to an interview and asked to implement a ring buffer with spin.. so I came up with this (I just assumed one producer and one consumer =p) ... I'm curious to see what kind of bugs you guys see, any comments... especially this line:

```
    if ((m_tail + 1) % m_size == m_head){
```

Is this thread-safe? Do I need a temporary atomic int to hold the calculate?

```
class RingBufferSpin {
private:
    std::atomic<bool> m_ready;
    std::atomic<int> m_head;
    std::atomic<int> m_tail;
    int *m_data;
    int m_size;
public:
    RingBufferSpin(int size){
        m_data = new int[size];
        m_size = size;
        m_head = 0;
        m_tail = 0;
    }

    void Enqueue(int o){
        if ((m_tail + 1) % m_size == m_head){
            m_ready.store(false, memory_order_release);
            int *m_newdata = new int[m_size * 2];
            if (m_head > m_tail){
                memcpy(m_new_data, m_data, m_head);                
            } else if (m_tail < m_head){
                memcpy(m_new_data, m_data, m_head);                
                memcpy(m_new_data[(m_head + m_size)], m_data[m_tail], m_size - m_tail);                
            }
            delete[] m_data;
            m_data = m_newdata;
            m_ready.store(true, memory_order_release);
        }
        m_data[m_head] = o;
        m_head.store((m_head + 1) % m_size);
    }

    int Dequeue(){
        while(!m_ready.load(memory_order_acquire)){
            // __asm__ pause
        }
        int t = m_data[m_tail];
        m_tail.store(m_tail + 1 % m_size);
        return t;
    }

    ~RingBufferSpin(){
        delete[] m_data;
    }
}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: For code reviews, please post to [codereview.se].

Comment: `m_data = m_newdata; delete[] m_data;` Errr, what, you assign some value to `m_data` and then `delete` it immediately? And try to access an element of `m_data` later on? This doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @user2343873: You may want to swap these two lines?! `m_data = m_newdata;
            delete[] m_data;`

Comment: I guess you also never initialize `m_tail` and `m_head` ?

Comment: Thanks, done! I'm more curious about my lock/atomic stuff, whether it's threadsafe, etc.